# I want to have extra characters that will serve as divider my to string

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub SaveInLogs(isThereNewLogs As Boolean, value As String)

    Dim list As List(Of String)
    Try
        list = Strings.Split(value, "#-!-#").ToList
        list(2) = "Incoming"
        For Each word In list
            MsgBox(list)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

The value of paramater "value" is this :
7/28/2016 10:19:27 AM#-!-#Alex17282016#-!-#Outgoing#-!-#Alex#-!-#Alex#-!-#Text#-!-#1ST

Then I split the values and change the word Outgoing to Incoming.

Now I want my string to  to look like this again
7/28/2016 10:19:27 AM#-!-#Alex17282016#-!-#Incoming#-!-#Alex#-!-#Alex#-!-#Text#-!-#1ST

Sorry for my grammar. I hope you understand my question

Comment: Why are you splitting the string in the first place? What's wrong with [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/fk49wtc1(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: Why not just use JSON? It's more easier and practical. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but maybe `Dim newValue As String = String.Join("#-!-#", list)`?

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for your answer, but what if the user's message is "Outgoing person"?. If I use String.Replace, the output would be "7/28/2016 10:19:27 AM#-!-#Alex17282016#-!-#Incoming#-!-#Alex#-!-#Alex#-!-#Text#-!-#Incoming Person"

Comment: `value = value.replace("#-!-#Outgoing#-!-#", "#-!-#Incoming#-!-#")` this way it wont replace outgoing person to incoming person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I have edited your code you already have to make the string the way you want it after changing "Outgoing" to "Incoming":

```
Sub SaveInLogs(isThereNewLogs As Boolean, value As String)

Dim list As List(Of String)
Dim newValue as String = ""
Try
    list = Strings.Split(value, "#-!-#").ToList
    list(2) = "Incoming"

    For Each word In list
        newValue = newValue & word
    Next

    value = newValue
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

End Sub
```

Or as Mark in the comments stated you could use string.join instead of a loop:

```
Sub SaveInLogs(isThereNewLogs As Boolean, value As String)

Dim list As List(Of String)
Try
    list = Strings.Split(value, "#-!-#").ToList
    list(2) = "Incoming"

    Dim newValue As String = String.Join("#-!-#", list)

Catch ex As Exception
End Try

End Sub
```

Below is code I think would work better, as it does it one line of code and doesn't need to split the string apart and put it back together:

```
Sub SaveInLogs(isThereNewLogs As Boolean, value As String)

    value = value.replace("#-!-#Outgoing#-!-#", "#-!-#Incoming#-!-#")

End Sub
```